# Pidfile should not get deleted when i do pkill -9 pid

Tags: linux, redhat, service, rhel7

I have a service snmpAgent. I do not want to delete the pid file when i do "pkill -9 $pid". But the pid file is getting deleted any help will be great.

Please find below my snmpAgent.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=SNMP 
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=$SNMPAGENT_HOME/pids/snmpagent.pid
User=$SAL_USER
ExecStart=$SNMPAGENT_HOME/scripts/snmpAgentserviceStartStop.sh snmpAgentstart
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
SuccessExitStatus=129

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: i have another application which restarts the service automatically if the pid is present but the process does not exists...but this is not happening now because of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like systemd doing a bit of cleanup.  Since you are running systemd and your purpose is to automate restart why not just request that systemd automatically restart the agent by adding Restart=always (or similar)to the [Service] section.  Then your other app's restart functionality  becomes redundant.

Comment: This is not the purpose..say if i had purposely stopped the service then the pid file should get deleted and the restart should not happen.

Comment: That's how it works with systemd.  It knows not to restart it because you just told systemd directly to stop it.  Using another program to handle this is added complexity that's not necessary.  If you want to manage the start and stop of the application outside of systemd, take it out of systemd.